# Issues with Npm in Node Windows executable

Tags: node.js, npm

### Problem

I recently updated to the latest version of node which is *supposed* to come with npm pre-installed. Although all the files are there, when I try to call something like `npm help` in node I get a hanging `...`. If I try to run it directly from command prompt I get this error:

[image: command prompt error]

Any Idea on what the possible issue could be? I am running on windows 7 btw.

### Ideas

- Pathing issues?
- Conflict with previous installation?
- Should I just install manually rather than the executable?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call npm with node, if you want to see if npm is installed properly (and is in your path) execute the following command in the terminal:

`npm -v`

If you want to install a module: `npm install express`

Comment: Ahh, so does npm actually run off node even though it is not executed through it, or is it a separate program all together? Also, what does the `-v` attached at the end do? Thanks for the help!

Comment: npm is a separate program, even if it's bundled with node. `npm -v` means 'what is the current version of npm I have installed?'